# Cuda Compute Mode and 'CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED'

Tags: cuda

I have a host in our cluster with 8 `Nvidia K80`s and I would like to set it up so that each device can run at most 1 process. Before, if I ran multiple jobs on the host and each use a large amount of memory, they would all attempt to hit the same device and fail.

I set all the devices to compute mode 3 (`E. Process`) via `nvidia-smi -c 3` which I believe makes it so that each device can accept a job from only one CPU process. I then run 2 jobs (each of which only takes about ~`150 MB` out of `12 GB` of memory on the device) *without* specifying `cudaSetDevice`, but the second job fails with `ERROR: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED`, rather than going to the second available device.

I am modeling my assumptions off of [this](https://www.wiki.ed.ac.uk/display/ecdfwiki/CUDA+programming+under+Compute-Exclusive+Mode) site's explanation and was expecting each job to cascade onto the next device, but it is not working. Is there something I am missing?

UPDATE: I ran `Matlab` using `gpuArray` in multiple different instances, and it is correctly cascading the `Matlab` jobs onto different devices. Because of this, I believe I am correctly setting up the compute modes at the OS level. Aside from `cudaSetDevice`, what could be forcing my `CUDA` code to lock into device 0?

Answer (score 3):

This is relying on an officially undocumented behavior (or else prove me wrong and point out the official documentation, please)  of the CUDA runtime that would, when a device was set to an Exclusive compute mode, automatically select another available device, when one is in use.

The CUDA runtime apparently enforced this behavior but it was "broken" in CUDA 7.0.

[My understanding](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/869602/cuda-7-0-and-compute-exclusive-mode-on-multi-gpu-machine/) is that it should have been "fixed" again in CUDA 7.5.

My guess is you are running CUDA 7.0 on those nodes.  If so, I would try updating to CUDA 7.5, or else revert to CUDA 6.5 if you really need this behavior.

It's suggested, rather than relying on this, that you instead use an external means, such as a job scheduler (e.g. Torque) to manage resources in a situation like this.

Comment: Actually, I am using a job scheduler, but have had trouble getting it to play nice with the devices - hence my resolution to simply lock each device into no more than one process. Also ... we are using 7.0 - time to re-image to 7.5 and see if it fixes things!